# Multiple choice Angular App -Show Answer-

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have developed a single page multiple choice quiz web application using AngularJS. I am trying to get the correct answer from the array list to show once the user selects a wrong answer after hitting the submit button inside the  tags. I know it's something simple, I know I'm over analysing it to make it seem more complex than what it's not. Every attempt I made show all of the option choices from the array list or either the correct number position value in the array list instead of the single correct answer. I'm also still new to using AngularJS.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quizApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QuizApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">QuizApp</h1>
        <quiz/>
    </div>
</body>
```

**template**

```
<div class="quiz-area" ng-show="inProgress">
<div ng-show="!quizOver">
    <h2 id="question">{{question}}</h2>
    <ul id="options">
        <li ng-repeat="option in options">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{option}}">
                {{option}}
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" ng-show="answerMode">Submit</button>

            <div ng-show="!answerMode">
        <button ng-click="nextQuestion()" class="next-question">Next</button>
        <span ng-show="correctAns">That is correct!</span>
        <span ng-show="!correctAns">Sorry, that is an incorrect answer.</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="quizOver">
    <h2>Quiz is over</h2>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Play again</button>
</div>

<div id="score">
    Score: {{score}}
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);
app.directive('quiz', function(quizFactory) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.start = function() {
            scope.id = 0;
            scope.quizOver = false;
            scope.inProgress = true;
            scope.getQuestion();
        };

        scope.reset = function() {
            scope.inProgress = false;
            scope.score = 0;
        }

        scope.getQuestion = function() {
            var q = quizFactory.getQuestion(scope.id);
            if(q) {
                scope.question = q.question;
                scope.options = q.options;
                scope.answer = q.answer;
                scope.answerMode = true;
            } else {
                scope.quizOver = true;
            }
        };

        scope.checkAnswer = function() {
            if(!$('input[name=answer]:checked').length) return;

            var ans = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val();

            if(ans == scope.options[scope.answer]) {
                scope.score++;
                scope.correctAns = true;
            } else {
                scope.correctAns = false;
            }

            scope.answerMode = false;
        };

        scope.nextQuestion = function() {
            scope.id++;
            scope.getQuestion();
        }

        scope.reset();
    }
}
});

app.factory('quizFactory', function() {
var questions = [
    {
        question: "Which is the largest country in the world by population?",
        options: ["India", "USA", "China", "Russia"],
        answer: 2
    },
    {
        question: "When did the second world war end?",
        options: ["1945", "1939", "1944", "1942"],
        answer: 0
    },
    {
        question: "Which was the first country to issue paper currency?",
        options: ["USA", "France", "Italy", "China"],
        answer: 3
    },
    {
        question: "Which city hosted the 1996 Summer Olympics?",
        options: ["Atlanta", "Sydney", "Athens", "Beijing"],
        answer: 0
    },
    {   
        question: "Who invented telephone?",
        options: ["Albert Einstein", "Alexander Graham Bell", "Isaac Newton", "Marie Curie"],
        answer: 1
    }
];

return {
    getQuestion: function(id) {
        if(id < questions.length) {
            return questions[id];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
});
```